# Conditionally finding groups of duplicate column pairs, if one of the pairs contains a specific flag. Then updating all to that txId

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am new to SQL. Bad data got inserted into a table. The table represents items that a user has purchased. txId is an id generated upon purchase. The assumption is each item/user combination all have the same txId.

```
id | item   | user     | txId    | date (ms)
-----------------------------------------------
1  | cup    | bob      |   10    | 1000000
2  | cup    | bob      |   -1    | 1000000
3  | cup    | bob      |   10    | 1000000
4  | cup    | jim      |   -1    | 2000000
5  | hat    | bob      |   10    | 1000000
6  | pen    | tom      |   -1    | 3000000
7  | pen    | tom      |   -1    | 3000000
8  | pen    | tom      |   13    | 3000000
9  | shoe   | bob      |   10    | 1000000
10 | hat    | dan      |   -1    | 4000000
11 | hat    | dan      |   -1    | 4000000
```

I am trying to find all item/sku groups that have a txId of -1 AND another valid txId (that is not -1). I don't care about line 4, since cup/jim is only 1 row of item/user. Line 5/9 also only have 1 row for the item/user group. Line 10/11 do not have a valid transaction id, so I don't want them either.

I want my results to be:

```
id | item   | user     | txId    | date (ms)
-----------------------------------------------
1  | cup    | bob      |   10    | 1000000
2  | cup    | bob      |   -1    | 1000000
3  | cup    | bob      |   10    | 1000000
6  | pen    | tom      |   -1    | 3000000
7  | pen    | tom      |   -1    | 3000000
8  | pen    | tom      |   13    | 3000000
```

Here is what I have tried

```
select groups.id, groups.item, groups.user, groups.txId, groups.date
from ( 
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (
    SELECT
        *
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY item, user) AS occurrences
    FROM myTable tbl
    ) t
    WHERE t.occ > 1
) groups
INNER JOIN 
( 
    SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE txId = -1
) violators
ON violators.user = groups.user AND violators.item = groups.item
ORDER BY groups.user, groups.item DESC
```

I am getting some false positives and can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.txid > 0 and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.item = t.item and t2.user = t.usr and
                     t2.txid < 0
              )
      ) or
      (t.txid < 0 and
       exists (select 1
               from t t2
               where t2.item = t.item and t2.user = t.usr and
                     t2.txid > 0
              )
      );
```

You can also use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             min(txid) over (partition by item, user) as min_txid,
             max(txid) over (partition by item, user) as max_txid
      from t
     ) t
where min_txid = -1 and max_txid > 0;
```